# How can I insert some list entries to kivy spinner values automatically?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, spinner

I am building a GUI and having difficulty assigning spinner values in my .kv file from some list that I've defined in my .py file. I've searched a lot for this problem but couldn't find any decent way to solve it. I've attached some code snippets of my .pyand .kv file. Hope this helps
**main.py**

```
fruits = ['Apples', 'Banans']   # I want these values assigned automatically to spinner values

class MainWindow(Screen):
# here i want fruits lsit values assigned to kivy spinner values 
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Robot(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen =  Builder.load_file('ali.kv')

    def build(self):
         self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"  # "Light"

    
    return self.screen



if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
         resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
         Robot().run()
```

**kv.kv**

```
    WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'mic.png'

    FloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: 'COM Port'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": 0.64}
            font_style: 'H6'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: (0.8941,0.8235,0.5843,0.74)
            #halign: 'center'


        Spinner:
            text:'Available COM Ports'
            text_color: 0.8941,0.8235,0.5843,0.74
            # available values
            values: ['Apples', 'Bananas'] # I want list values of 
            # just for positioning in our example
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            background_normal : ''
            background_color : 0.8941,0.8235,0.5843,0.74   # blue colour
            
        MDRoundFlatButton: 
            text: 'Submit'
            text_color: 0.8941,0.8235,0.5843,0.74
            on_release: app.root.current = 'second'
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y':0.5}
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can give the Spinner an id.

```
       Spinner:
           id:my_spinner
           text:'Available COM Ports'
           text_color: 0.8941,0.8235,0.5843,0.74
           # available values
           values: ['Apples', 'Bananas'] # I want list values of 
           # just for positioning in our example
           size_hint: None, None
           size: 100, 44
           pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
           background_normal : ''
           background_color : 0.8941,0.8235,0.5843,0.74   # blue colour
```

After that you can use the id to reference in your python code.

```
self.root.ids.my_spinner.values = ['Apples', 'Bananas']
```

If you want to add the values one by one you can use loop and append to list then write it into the spinner since spinner values are just a list of strings. Check [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html#kivy.uix.spinner.Spinner.values)

Comment: I understand the method but i find it difficult to implement due to complex nature of list properties. I have a list of 5 itmes and i want to append it one by one using for loop in my MainWindow class. So in this regard, can you please elaborate it further?